# Apache Pig Query - Dataset Joins ERROR 1031

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have the following four tasks to work on but am confused on how to join the two datasets to get any of the tasks to work properly...

A) Query customer name that have the least number of transactions and output customer names, and the number of transactions.

B) Join Customers and Transactions using Broadcast (replicated) join. Report: CustomerID, Name, Salary, NumOf Transactions, TotalSum, MinItems (Where NumOfTransactions is the total number of transactions done by the customer, TotalSum is the sum of field “TransTotal” for that customer, and MinItems is the minimum number of items in transactions done by the customer.)

C) Report the Country Codes having number of customers greater than 5,000 or less than 2,000.

D) Assume we want to design an analytics task on the data as follows: the Age attribute is divided into six groups, which are [10, 20), [20, 30), [30, 40), [40, 50), [50, 60), and [60, 70]. Within each of the above age ranges, further division is performed based on the “Gender”, i.e., each of the 6 age groups is further divided into two groups. Each group reports: Age Range, Gender, MinTransTotal, MaxTransTotal, AvgTransTotal. Note: The bracket “[“ means the lower bound of a range is included, where as “)” means the upper bound of a range is excluded.

This is what I have started with:

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /piginput
sudo hadoop fs -put customer.txt /piginput
sudo hadoop fs -put transaction.txt /piginput
sudo hadoop fs -put transaction_small.txt /piginput

pig 

customers = LOAD '/piginput/customers.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (id:int,name:chararray,age:int,gender:chararray,CountryCode:int,salary:float);

transactions = LOAD '/piginput/transaction.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (trans_id:int, id:int, age:int, total:float, num_items:int, description:chararray);

alldata = JOIN customers BY id, transactions BY id;

by_clusters_terms_count = FOREACH alldata COUNT(id);
```

which produces the error:

### Pig Stack Trace

```
ERROR 1031: Incompatable schema: left is          "id:NULL,name:NULL,num_items:NULL", right is "customers::id:int"

Failed to parse: Pig script failed to parse: 
<line 4, column 26> pig script failed to validate:     org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1031:     Incompatable schema: left is "id:NULL,name:NULL,num_items:NULL", right is     "customers::id:int"
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:196)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.validateQuery(PigServer.java:1684)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1657)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:600)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:1069)
at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:501)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:228)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:203)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:66)
at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:542)
at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
Caused by: 
<line 4, column 26> pig script failed to validate:     org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1031: Incompatable schema: left is "id:NULL,name:NULL,num_items:NULL", right is "customers::id:int"
at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildForeachOp(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:1041)
at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.foreach_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:15870)
at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.op_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1933)
at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.general_statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1102)
at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:560)
at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.query(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:421)
at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:188)
... 15 more
Caused by: org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1031: Incompatable schema: left is "id:NULL,name:NULL,num_items:NULL", right is "customers::id:int"
at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LogicalSchema.merge(LogicalSchema.java:760)
at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOGenerate.getSchema(LOGenerate.java:158)
at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.SchemaResetter.visit(SchemaResetter.java:123)
at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOGenerate.accept(LOGenerate.java:245)
at org.apache.pig.newplan.DependencyOrderWalker.walk(DependencyOrderWalker.java:75)
at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.SchemaResetter.visit(SchemaResetter.java:114)
at     org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildForeachOp(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:1039)
... 21 more
```

Any ideas? Am I joining the datasets incorrectly causing an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
customers = LOAD 'hdfs://hadoop-VirtualBox:8020/piginput/customer.txt' USING  PigStorage(',') AS  (id:int,name:chararray,age:int,gender:chararray,CountryCode:int,salary:float);
 A = foreach customers generate id, name;
 transactions = LOAD 'hdfs://hadoop-VirtualBox:8020/piginput/transaction_small.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (trans_id:int, cust_id:int, total:float, num_items:int,  description:chararray);
 B = foreach transactions generate cust_id,num_items; 
 alldata = JOIN A BY id, B BY cust_id;
 C = GROUP alldata by $0;
```

This ended up working and fixing the issues